# How can I adjust ='s alignment of C-style comments?

Tags: vimrc, indentation, alignment

I'd like `=` to indent block C-style comments like this:

```
/*
  Comment.
*/
```

not this:

```
/*
  Comment.
 */
```

Note the extra space before the last `*`. (I would like to automatically align the first `/` and the last `*` at the current indentation level.)

What is a simple way, preferably compatible with `autoindent`, to specify this in my `.vimrc`?

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust the indent of the end comment by setting the `'comments'` option. e.g.:

```
:set comments=s:/*,m:\ ,e-3:*/
```

This is documented at `:help 'comments'` and `:help format-comments`.

You might also want to look into how you currently have it set by using the command: `:verbose set comments`.

You probably should also consider using `'cindent'` instead of `'autoindent'`, and if you do so, you may want to take a look at: `:help cino-C`, which will allow you to tweak the indent of that middle line.

Comment: Very helpful. I will add, for future visitors, that putting the above in my `.vimrc` didn't immediately work, since there are `ftplugin` settings overriding (which is also revealed by `:verbose set comments`).

Comment: Use the after-directory to set your own personal `'filetype'` settings, e.g. `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim`. For more help see `:h after-directory`.